# results from php library not working with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm calling the uberGallery (www.uberGallery.net) from the index.php like so:

```
<?php

include_once 'resources/UberGallery.php';
include_once 'resources/uberCall.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        ...

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/themes/uber-naked/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/colorbox/5/colorbox.css" />

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "row">
            <div  class = "col col-lg-12">
                <h2 id = "locName"></h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="gallery">
            <?php
            $path = "london";
            getGallery($path);

            $path = "paris";
            getGallery($path);

            $path = "rome";
            getGallery($path);
            ?>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src='js/UX.js'></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The uberCall.php is like that:

```
<?php
include_once ('UberGallery.php');

function getGallery($pathToImage){
        UberGallery::init() -> createGallery('locations/'.$pathToImage.'/gallery');
    }

if(isset( $_POST['image-path'] )) {

    $path = $_POST['image-path'];

    UberGallery::init() -> createGallery('locations/'.$path.'/gallery');

}

?>
```

So far this is working like expected.
Now I would like to load the galleries from a dropdown menue and just show the selected gallery. The dropdown selection is done in a jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a[rel='colorbox']").colorbox({
        maxWidth : "90%",
        maxHeight : "90%",
        opacity : ".5"
    });

    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();

    $('#demolist li a').click(function(e) {
        $('#locationSelector').val($(this).text());
        var $this = $(this);
        var selLocID = $this.attr("value");

        e.preventDefault();

        var dataString = {
            'location_id' : selLocID
        };

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            url : 'includes/locationAPI.php',
            data : dataString,
            success : function(data) {
                $('#locData').html('');
                // erase content if any

                $('#locName').html(data['name']);
                // from MySQL
                // set location headline

                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    data : {
                        'image-path' : data['pfad'] // from MySQL
                    },
                    url : 'resources/uberCall.php',
                    dataType : "html",
                    async : false,
                    success : function(data) {
                        result = data;

                        alert(result);
                        $('#gallery').html(result);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });

});
```

When going this route the ubergallery doesn't find any folders, though I'm adressing the exact same uber.php as I would from the index.php. 
I have looked into the ubergallery.php with xdebug and it would be called with exactly the same parameters.

Also I tried to call createGallery() without init:: and also explicitly create a new instance of the UberGallery class before calling createGallery.

All with no luck.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think that there is a problem with the path `locations/'.$pathToImage.'/gallery`, because it is a relative path so that it is different when you'll call index.php or resources/uberCall.php

Comment: Thanks mapek, exactly that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>In your `resources/userCall.php` script you are not actually calling the gallery function in order to render it. This appears to be the target of the second AJAX request. The script is merely defining the function.</strike>

**EDIT**: You've since updated the code in your question to include the call.

Assuming `image-path` is the parameter you want to supply as `$pathToImage` you will need to have a script that calls the function `getGallery` passing the value from `$_POST['image-path']`.

For example:

```
<?php
require_once('resources/uberCall.php');

getGallery($_POST['image-path']);
```

> **NOTE:** Without any filtering sanitisation, bear in mind this could be potentially **dangerous** as I could pass an `image-path` parameter that picks a naughty directory.

Then use that script as the target of your second AJAX call.

**P.S.** Remove the `async: false` in the second AJAX call, it stops any other interactivity on your page whilst the request is in flight.

Bear in mind that with your parameter checking in the `resources/userCall.php` the original request is down a directory from the second request. This means the working directory for the second request will be different, the path will resolve to `"resources/locations/$path/gallery"` and not `"locations/$path/gallery"`.

You are best off creating a second script for the AJAX action in the same directory as the original and requiring in the `resource/userCall.php` as per the first script. Or using a configurable absolute directory path to resolve the gallery location:

```
<?php
require_once('UberGallery.php');
require_once('config.php');

function getGallery($path) {
  UberGallery::init() -> createGallery("{$config['gallery_base_path']}/$path/gallery");
}
```

With `$config['gallery_base_path']` being something like `/absolute/path/to/my/application/locations`.

Additional confusion can be caused by not knowing whether file operations will use the include path, some file options can be told to use the include path which may include the current file path and current script directory, but if not it will only try to find the file from the current working directory. Whereas `include` and `require` all use the include path and current script directory as potential points to find a script.

**P.S.P.S** Use [getcwd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) to find out what the current working directory is at any point in your scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining this in so much detail Stuart. I solved it by pushing the uberCall.php in the root directory so it's now searching in 'locations/$path/gallery'. As you suggested it was looking in 'resources/locations/$path/gallery' folder which is not existing.